# Why this Swift code doesn't work - mixing Objective-C class in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a huge background as c++ dev, but I'm still newbie in Swift/Objective-C zone. I'm trying to build a class hierarchy and I'm kind of stuck with this code:

```
protocol CADelegate : class {
    func g()
}

class CA : NSObject {
    init(i: Int) {}

    func f() {
        if let del = getDelegate() {
            del.g()
        } else {
            println("delegate is null")
        }
    }

    private func getDelegate() -> CADelegate? {
        return nil
    }
}

class CB : CA {
    override init(i: Int) {
        super.init(i:i)
    }

    var delegate: CADelegate!

    private override func getDelegate() -> CADelegate? {
        return delegate
    }
}

class Client : CADelegate {
    func g() {
        println("CA delegate")
    }
}

class ViewController : ... {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var cb = CB(i: 1)
        var client = Client()
        cb.delegate = client // the problem row!!!
        cb.f()
    }
}
```

On "the problem row" I got an runtime error EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=...).

Can somebody help me figure this out? I know I'm doing something wrong, because I'm use to C++ idioms and programming style.

NOTE: also the same is true if the delegate property is weak, as it is in my original code.

Edit 1:
I'm using XCode6 Beta 7

Edit 2:
As it turns out it is not 100% reproducible. 3 out of 5 times it is working but for the other 2 times I've got the bad access exception. It looks like a race condition, but I'm not using any other tasks/threads. This is my main view controller and viewDidLoad should be called on view controller initialization.

Edit 3:
Even more strange - if I remove my constructors in CA and CB, and change the creation of CB without int parameter, the problem disappears! I'm sure now it looks like a bug :)

Comment: Stop using semicolons!!

Comment: But semicolons are allowed, they are part of the Swift language. ;-)

Comment: I know the ; are not mandatory, but I like them ;)